# Jasper Report not add multiple page

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a report with multiple pages in jasper report to do it I read that it is necessary to insert a page break, when I insert the page break but the "jump" to the next page is not performed this the content always remains on the first page , how can i fix this?

**Jasper file xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reportpreventivo" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3c08ffac-5031-449c-a58f-007dffeebf2f">
    <import value="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64"/>
    <subDataset name="DataSetHeader" uuid="db6131ae-8b7b-429e-aaca-42479bc8befd">
        <parameter name="Data" class="java.lang.String">
            <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Data del preventivo]]></parameterDescription>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="NRPreventivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="NSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Titolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="RagioneSociale" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Oggetto" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Testata" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="LogoBase64" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="Data" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="NSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="VSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="NRPreventivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Titolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="RagioneSociale" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Chiusura" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Testata" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Oggetto" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="LogoBase64" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <variable name="Logo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="DataSetTableValori" uuid="797e3017-223a-44f4-86f7-e13073e06538">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="NumeroCapitolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Descrizione" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Desc2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SottoCapitolo1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SottoCapitolo2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SottoCapitolo3" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="DescrizioneDis" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="CostoUnitario" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Quantita" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="TotaleCap" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="DescrizioneEstesa" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Tipologia" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="UM" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="PrezzoRiservato" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Images" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Data" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="NRPreventivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="NSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="VSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Titolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="RagioneSociale" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Indirizzo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Citta" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Oggetto" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Testata" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="LogoBase64" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="258">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout"/>
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="-10" width="555" height="79" uuid="7fe6f2e0-3ba7-4424-9383-8d78bfe1cc21"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["http://centoimpianti.com/immagini/logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="30" y="128" width="500" height="130" uuid="a5a724e9-c81f-470a-8a83-9dd6bfbd823d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Testata}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="30" y="228" width="500" height="30" uuid="089a3b80-f7df-461b-be75-bcad575bf4e9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Oggetto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="170" width="170" height="30" uuid="9174f886-5c23-4f99-9c97-86fb50f6eeb3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Citta}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="140" width="170" height="30" uuid="ec9b01f4-bcb2-495f-9a54-efc48bb452c8"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Indirizzo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="110" width="170" height="30" uuid="caf5fd23-70c3-46d3-9de0-c5765c1ec5fc"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{RagioneSociale}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="75" width="100" height="15" uuid="7231c72c-d715-4bbe-8906-a27173f77220"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Titolo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="170" width="100" height="30" uuid="aac1e4b6-da6a-4e46-aa0f-c026896a3b86"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{VSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="170" width="90" height="30" uuid="dc708ab1-3286-479d-ad0b-aaea351652b4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Vs.Rif:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="140" width="100" height="30" uuid="1a11a6cc-5d1b-4994-bf10-3cc1de504d07"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{NSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="140" width="90" height="30" uuid="c5dbd3b3-7263-43d5-a804-1a797635fe8a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nf.Rif:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="110" width="100" height="30" uuid="b0632e23-c54a-4edc-a264-23055af446a5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{NRPreventivo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="90" width="90" height="30" uuid="c59e786f-e907-4bcd-93f3-a14d0b777d5c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nr Preventivo:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="70" y="75" width="100" height="15" uuid="29f6924b-5bd2-42f1-bd98-0090aed0d3eb"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Data}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="75" width="40" height="15" uuid="801816f2-1988-4b9e-9291-88d5a200d238"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Data:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="277" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="470" y="220" width="100" height="30" uuid="980219d2-fe09-46a6-ad45-44b5a5d955dd"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="555" height="1" uuid="4c31b7fe-5ec5-49c1-b25b-86783bb78a04"/>
            </break>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="544" height="30" uuid="9eba7646-c8ff-4a47-9bdf-80e761574024"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DataSetHeader" uuid="71f5f8c7-7482-43ce-9fb5-b7ae826aac48">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="544">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="f858cba9-20e9-4617-ab6c-bdc90729455f"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Data}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="c3ccd40f-c529-49ef-b06e-06f53ed59235"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="ee277db1-87e9-4d49-9a2c-ce3c31b758ac"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{VSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="98fa3e12-b8f6-4cb0-a68c-f8357cdf8145"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NRPreventivo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="40" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="c7f37047-c74b-458c-b067-d1fd24c9e1d3"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Titolo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="50" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="e7a1391b-a235-44d1-b40a-f1f84ba513aa"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RagioneSociale}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="d76e9074-d5a8-4329-b244-002ebef1395f"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Chiusura}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="70" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="aec60c88-6971-4d14-9e9d-f0499c048601"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Testata}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="80" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="a198722f-4da1-49dc-8788-4a4a12e12b0e"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Oggetto}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="3bd98713-7742-49bc-9a12-6c666cc6e809"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LogoBase64}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="155" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page break is in the band page footer, so it is always at the end of the page. If you want to break between some fields you have to put it in the right band and between those fields. Here is your example with break after "Nr Preventivo:"

```
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.19.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reportpreventivo" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3c08ffac-5031-449c-a58f-007dffeebf2f">
    <import value="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64"/>
    <subDataset name="DataSetHeader" uuid="db6131ae-8b7b-429e-aaca-42479bc8befd">
        <parameter name="Data" class="java.lang.String">
            <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Data del preventivo]]></parameterDescription>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="NRPreventivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="NSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Titolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="RagioneSociale" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Oggetto" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Testata" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="LogoBase64" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="Data" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="NSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="VSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="NRPreventivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Titolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="RagioneSociale" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Chiusura" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Testata" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Oggetto" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="LogoBase64" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <variable name="Logo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="DataSetTableValori" uuid="797e3017-223a-44f4-86f7-e13073e06538">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="NumeroCapitolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Descrizione" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Desc2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SottoCapitolo1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SottoCapitolo2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SottoCapitolo3" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="DescrizioneDis" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="CostoUnitario" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Quantita" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="TotaleCap" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="DescrizioneEstesa" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Tipologia" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="UM" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="PrezzoRiservato" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Images" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Data" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="NRPreventivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="NSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="VSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Titolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="RagioneSociale" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Indirizzo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Citta" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Oggetto" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Testata" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="LogoBase64" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="259">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="30" y="128" width="500" height="130" uuid="a5a724e9-c81f-470a-8a83-9dd6bfbd823d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Testata}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="30" y="228" width="500" height="30" uuid="089a3b80-f7df-461b-be75-bcad575bf4e9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Oggetto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="170" width="170" height="30" uuid="9174f886-5c23-4f99-9c97-86fb50f6eeb3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Citta}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="140" width="170" height="30" uuid="ec9b01f4-bcb2-495f-9a54-efc48bb452c8"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Indirizzo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="110" width="170" height="30" uuid="caf5fd23-70c3-46d3-9de0-c5765c1ec5fc"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{RagioneSociale}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="75" width="100" height="15" uuid="7231c72c-d715-4bbe-8906-a27173f77220"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Titolo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="170" width="100" height="30" uuid="aac1e4b6-da6a-4e46-aa0f-c026896a3b86"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{VSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="170" width="90" height="30" uuid="dc708ab1-3286-479d-ad0b-aaea351652b4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Vs.Rif:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="140" width="100" height="30" uuid="1a11a6cc-5d1b-4994-bf10-3cc1de504d07"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{NSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="140" width="90" height="30" uuid="c5dbd3b3-7263-43d5-a804-1a797635fe8a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nf.Rif:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="110" width="100" height="30" uuid="b0632e23-c54a-4edc-a264-23055af446a5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{NRPreventivo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="90" width="90" height="30" uuid="c59e786f-e907-4bcd-93f3-a14d0b777d5c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nr Preventivo:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="70" y="75" width="100" height="15" uuid="29f6924b-5bd2-42f1-bd98-0090aed0d3eb"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Data}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="75" width="40" height="15" uuid="801816f2-1988-4b9e-9291-88d5a200d238"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Data:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="125" width="552" height="1" uuid="4c31b7fe-5ec5-49c1-b25b-86783bb78a04"/>
            </break>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="277" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="470" y="220" width="100" height="30" uuid="980219d2-fe09-46a6-ad45-44b5a5d955dd"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="544" height="30" uuid="9eba7646-c8ff-4a47-9bdf-80e761574024"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DataSetHeader" uuid="71f5f8c7-7482-43ce-9fb5-b7ae826aac48">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="544">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="f858cba9-20e9-4617-ab6c-bdc90729455f"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Data}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="c3ccd40f-c529-49ef-b06e-06f53ed59235"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="ee277db1-87e9-4d49-9a2c-ce3c31b758ac"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{VSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="98fa3e12-b8f6-4cb0-a68c-f8357cdf8145"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NRPreventivo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="40" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="c7f37047-c74b-458c-b067-d1fd24c9e1d3"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Titolo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="50" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="e7a1391b-a235-44d1-b40a-f1f84ba513aa"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RagioneSociale}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="d76e9074-d5a8-4329-b244-002ebef1395f"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Chiusura}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="70" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="aec60c88-6971-4d14-9e9d-f0499c048601"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Testata}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="80" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="a198722f-4da1-49dc-8788-4a4a12e12b0e"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Oggetto}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="10" height="30" uuid="3bd98713-7742-49bc-9a12-6c666cc6e809"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LogoBase64}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="155" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```